# Rails includes with conditions on self association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

I have model named Player with type main or child with self association named children

and than there is model named Event in which Player registers as main Player or child Player , relations are following

**Player**

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Player', foreign_key: 'player_id'
  has_many :events, :through => :event_players
  has_many :event_players,dependent: :destroy

  enum player_type: [:main, :child]
end
```

**Event**

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :players, :through => :event_players
  has_many :event_players,dependent: :destroy
end
```

**EventPlayer**

```
class EventPlayer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :player
end
```

Now for a specific event I want to see all main players which are not registered in an event along with children of each main player, also don't include children which are not registered.
I have to **eager load** children as there are too many records and can't query for each main player to get his children.

I am trying like this

```
// get those players registered in event
excluded_ids = EventPlayer.where(event_id: params[:event_id]).pluck(:player_id)

// than exclude these players to get unregistered players
players = Player.where(player_type: 'main').includes(:children).where.not("players.id IN(?)",excluded_ids )

// now get unregistered child players of any main player it gives all children 
children = players.first.children
enter code here
```

what it does it get unregistered main players fine but when I try to fetch its included children it gives all children ignoring any query, how should I apply query on children

**SCHEMA FOR TABLES** (removed unnecessary fields)

```
   create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
      t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
      t.string   "first_name"
      t.string   "last_name"
      t.integer  "player_id"
      t.integer  "player_type",            default: 0
   end

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
  end

  create_table "event_players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.integer  "player_id"
    t.integer  "status",        default: 0
    t.integer  "invited_by_id"
  end
```

**RESPONSE REQUIRED**

I want response like this, an array of players with its children (eager loaded)
but none of them has be in registered in event

```
players:[
  {
    name: "player1",
    children:[
      {
        name: "player1's child1"
      }, 
      {
        name: "player1's child2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "player2",
    children:[
      {
        name: "palyer2's child1"
      }, 
      {
        name: "palyer2's child2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you add the migrations for those tables?

Comment: sure, in a minute

Comment: @SebastianPalma added schema for these tables

Comment: Can you try `Player.where(player_type: 'main').includes(:children).where.not("players.id IN(?)", excluded_ids).joins(:children).where(players: { ... })`. Being a self join you should use `joins` with the association name, but where must use the table name (players).

Comment: same result with .joins(:children).where.not(players: {id: excluded_ids})

Comment: What exactly are you trying? What about appending `references(:children)` to the query?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I edited question to add response I want, issue is this that its returning registered children and applying query only on main players.